# Reverse last i element in array python

Tags: python

I want to reverse the last x elements in a list in python.

For example - Reverse the last 3 elements.

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

# Output needed = [1,2,3,4,5,8,7,6]
```

Comment: `print(li[:-3] + li[-1:-4:-1])`

Comment: Well, you should also write the efforts you made and your code you tried

Comment: @ShivamJha What ? Not able to understand

Comment: Did you not understand the code, or what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the following command to do it -

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
count = 3 #Number of elements you want reverse from last.
a = a[:-count] + a[-count:][::-1]
print(a) #[1,2,3,4,5,8,7,6]
```